# App Engine health check not working

Tags: google-app-engine, healthcheck

This is my `app.yaml`

```
runtime: go112
instance_class: B1

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

liveness_check:
  path: "/health"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 1
  failure_threshold: 1
  initial_delay_sec: 10
```

App is not receiving health checks. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Health check is available just in "flexible" environment:

```
runtime: go
env: flex
```